# Package registration in Python versus IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, pydev, ibpy

I manually installed IbPy by using "python setup.py install" under windows and WinPython. The packages seem to appear in the right dirs;

```
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3\Lib\site-packages\ib\ext
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3\Lib\site-packages\ib\lib
etc.
```

Running:

```
from ib.ext.Contract  import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
```

works fine in IPython, but in Python and Eclipse I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ib.ext'; 'ib' is not a package
```

In Eclipse I can see ib and it subdirs as packages.

Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: In Eclipse, under Preferences, PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter, select your interpreter from the top, then in the bottom half, under the Libraries tab, is `C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3\Lib\site-packages` listed?

Comment: Yes, it is. To be sure I even included C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3\Lib\site-packages\ib  and its subdirs separately.

Comment: Do you have a file on your path named `ib.py`?  Maybe your script that you're doing all this in?

Comment: That solves it! My file was called ib.py .... Thx!